# Nested Comment System till three level in HTML

Tags: html, css

Following code is two level comment system. I would like to add one more nested level of reply. I have tried to changes so many code and created one more nested comment. But in that case image is not populating right alignment.

```css
/**
 * Oscuro: #283035
 * Azul: #03658c
 * Detalle: #c7cacb
 * Fondo: #dee1e3
 ----------------------------------*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: #03658c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif, Verdana;
  background: #dee1e3;
}


/** ====================
 * Lista de Comentarios
 =======================*/

.comments-container {
  margin: 60px auto 15px;
  width: 768px;
}

.comments-container h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #283035;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.comments-container h1 a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.comments-list {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}


/**
 * Lineas / Detalles
 -----------------------*/

.comments-list:before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #c7cacb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 32px;
  top: 0;
}

.comments-list:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #c7cacb;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 27px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #dee1e3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.reply-list:before,
.reply-list:after {
  display: none;
}

.reply-list li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #c7cacb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -55px;
}

.comments-list li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.comments-list li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.reply-list {
  padding-left: 88px;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 15px;
}


/**
 * Avatar
 ---------------------------*/

.comments-list .comment-avatar {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comments-list .comment-avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.reply-list .comment-avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.comment-main-level:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/**
 * Caja del Comentario
 ---------------------------*/

.comments-list .comment-box {
  width: 680px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.comments-list .comment-box:before,
.comments-list .comment-box:after {
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-width: 10px 12px 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #FCFCFC;
  top: 8px;
  left: -11px;
}

.comments-list .comment-box:before {
  border-width: 11px 13px 11px 0;
  border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  left: -12px;
}

.reply-list .comment-box {
  width: 610px;
}

.comment-box .comment-head {
  background: #FCFCFC;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.comment-box .comment-head i {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  color: #A6A6A6;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.comment-box .comment-head i:hover {
  color: #03658c;
}

.comment-box .comment-name {
  color: #283035;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.comment-box .comment-name a {
  color: #283035;
}

.comment-box .comment-head span {
  float: left;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.comment-box .comment-content {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #595959;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.comment-box .comment-name.by-author,
.comment-box .comment-name.by-author a {
  color: #03658c;
}

.comment-box .comment-name.by-author:after {
  content: 'autor';
  background: #03658c;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/** =====================
 * Responsive
 ========================*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .comments-container {
    width: 480px;
  }
  .comments-list .comment-box {
    width: 390px;
  }
  .reply-list .comment-box {
    width: 320px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Contenedor Principal -->
<div class="comments-container">
  <h1>Comentarios </h1>

  <ul id="comments-list" class="comments-list">
    <li>
      <div class="comment-main-level">
        <!-- Avatar -->
        <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_1_zps8e1c80cd.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
        <div class="comment-box">
          <div class="comment-head">
            <h6 class="comment-name by-author"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Agustin Ortiz</a></h6>
            <span>hace 20 minutos</span>
            <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="comment-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Respuestas de los comentarios -->
      <ul class="comments-list reply-list">
        <li>
          <!-- Avatar -->
          <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_2_zps7de12f8b.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
          <div class="comment-box">
            <div class="comment-head">
              <h6 class="comment-name"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Lorena Rojero</a></h6>
              <span>hace 10 minutos</span>
              <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <!-- Avatar -->
          <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_1_zps8e1c80cd.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
          <div class="comment-box">
            <div class="comment-head">
              <h6 class="comment-name by-author"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Agustin Ortiz</a></h6>
              <span>hace 10 minutos</span>
              <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="comment-main-level">
        <!-- Avatar -->
        <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_2_zps7de12f8b.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
        <div class="comment-box">
          <div class="comment-head">
            <h6 class="comment-name"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Lorena Rojero</a></h6>
            <span>hace 10 minutos</span>
            <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="comment-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can any one help one this?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I want to create 3 level of comment using same example. Above code is 2 level comment.